# Change line when meeting a specific character in php

Tags: php

I have a php variable which contains a large string. I want to echo the current variable and when i find the character ',' i just want to change line. For example, lets say i have the variable $content, and inside this variable i have the string  "user1,user2,user3". I want to echo the variable but to put a line break when i found the character ',' so when i echo the variable i want my result to be like this: 
user1
                        user2
                        user3

Is there any php function that i can use for this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you looked at [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)?

Comment: in html page or in php console

Comment: in html page not in the php console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) you can just replace the , with anything you want - for HTML...

```
$var = "user1,user2,user3";

$var = str_replace(",", "<br />", $var);
echo $var;
```

gives...

```
user1<br />user2<br />user3
```

Just change the second parameter to however you want the data to be separated.

Comment: Thanks man this was what i was looking for, thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

This would be the best and simplest solution :

```
$myvar = "hello , my name is Sina , I am a website developer & designer";
$result = str_replace(",","<br>", $myvar);
echo $result;
```

Answer (score 0):

The str_replace() function replaces some characters with some other characters in a string.

```
$string = 'user1,user2,user3';
$newString = str_replace(',','</br>',$string);
echo $newString;

//Output
 user1
 user2
 user3
```